# How can i call the same fancybox javascript from more than one link?

Tags: javascript, html, fancybox

The fancybox modal popup uses a bit of javascript:

```
$("#PeoplePopup").fancybox({
'autoScale'         : false,
'padding'           : 0,
'width'             : 800,
'height'            : 600,
'transitionIn'      : 'elastic',
'transitionOut'     : 'elastic',
'type'              : 'iframe',
'overlayColor'      : '#000',
'overlayOpacity'    : 0.5
});
```

which is fired when the link is clicked:

```
<a href = "peoplesearch.aspx"  class="SmallWhite" 
      id="PeoplePopup">Search for Internal Contact details &gt; </a>
```

How can I call the same popup code from multiple links?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

User `class` instead of `id`, so you can you call the popupcode mutliple time.

```
//html
<a href = "peoplesearch.aspx"  class="SmallWhite PeoplePopup">
         Search for Internal Contact details </a>

//other links
<a href = "peoplesearch2.aspx"  class="PeoplePopup">...</a>
<a href = "peoplesearch3.aspx"  class="PeoplePopup">...</a>

//this jquery code will apply to the three links above
$(".PeoplePopup").fancybox({
    //the same code here 
})
```

Comment: Perfect thanks! - my java is minimal tbh - i knew it would be something simple, i'll accept asap.

Answer (score 1):

While the provided answers are correct, I'd recommend giving jQuery some scope, otherwise you're searching for the existence of .PeoplePopup through the entire window object, e.g.

$('#PeopleContainer .PeoplePopup')

or

$('#PeopleContainer').find('.PeoplePopup')

While xpath selectors normally work left to right, jQuery understands how to optimize the first example.

if it's a small site, you won't notice the difference, but if you've got a dozen or more instances on the page and a pretty complex DOM, it will start to matter.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that - im using the popup to edit each element in a large table, what sort of issues can the situation you mention actually cause?

Comment: Selecting on classname alone can lead to slower performance. I learned this lesson the hard way about 5 years ago when applying a custom-built accordion plugin to a page of 100 or so divs. 

On slower machines, users would experience the dreaded "This script is taking a long time to run, do you want to wait or kill it?" error (I'm paraphrasing, as it's browser-dependent).

this:

$('.PeoplePopup')

has to search every element in the DOM, and check for that class.

$('#PeopleContainer').find('.PeoplePopup')

only searches within whatever element you've assigned the id "PeopleContainer" to.

Comment: Ah i see - that makes sense, so i put the first part as the name of the containing DIV?

Comment: yep! you mention a table layout, so <table id="PeopleContainer"> and a subsequent <td class="PeoplePopup"> would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Use classes instead of an ID

```
$(".PeoplePopup").fancybox({
'autoScale'         : false,
'padding'           : 0,
'width'             : 800,
'height'            : 600,
'transitionIn'      : 'elastic',
'transitionOut'     : 'elastic',
'type'              : 'iframe',
'overlayColor'      : '#000',
'overlayOpacity'    : 0.5
});
```

Then in each link where you need this, add the PeoplePopup class -

```
<a href = "peoplesearch.aspx"  class="SmallWhite PeoplePopup">Search for Internal Contact details &gt; </a>

<a href = "peoplesearch.aspx"  class="SmallWhite PeoplePopup">Internal Contact details &gt; </a>
```